# Java - getCardBackgroundColor - color for CardView

Tags: java, android, cardview

Can you help me with my code? I am changing the color of the item based on the information from the database, and now I wanted to transfer the color to the CardView, but I don't know what the notation should look like, because this code tells me that the Color.RED write is wrong. Will you help me?

```
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull holder holder, int position, @NonNull 
VoiceModel model) {

    holder.tvvoiceName.setText(model.getName());
    holder.tvvoiceTime.setText(model.getTime());
    if(model.getPremium() == 1) holder.voice_item.getCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setCardBackgroundColor` not `getCardBackgroundColor`. Then your code should be:

```
holder.voice_item.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
holder.voice_item.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.here_put_your_color));
```